# Displaying and manipulating ArrayList in Java Swing GUI

Tags: java, arrays, swing

This is a GUI with `Arraylist` in `Java`.  I'm trying to display the `ArrayList` in a nice arrangement on the center panel. It would be nice to see the entire list! What code would I have to add to make the current to a JList and display correctly. Also how do I add to the `ArrayList` from the input and add button at the top of GUI. Any ideas on what code would achieve this end?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class ArrayListGUI extends JPanel
{
// main method; runs application and sets up the JFrame
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ArrayList");
        ArrayListGUI content = new ArrayListGUI();
        frame.setContentPane(content);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800,690);
        frame.setLocation(75,50);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

// declare variables
   private JList message;
   private Action messageAction;
   private JButton removeAll, printL, saveF, quitA; //west
   private JButton az, za, rev, random; // east
   private JTextField inputBox;
   private JButton addButton;
   private JTextField sizeBox; // bottom

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public ArrayListGUI()
        {

        ArrayList<String> wordlist = new ArrayList<String>();
        // wordlist ArrayList has been created, now we add words to that list...
        // (data set from the Word Association Test - Carl Jung)
        wordlist.add("Head");
        wordlist.add("Green");
        wordlist.add("Water");
        wordlist.add("To sing");
        wordlist.add("Dead");
        wordlist.add("Long");
        wordlist.add("Ship");
        wordlist.add("To pay");
        wordlist.add("Window");
        wordlist.add("Friendly");
        wordlist.add("To cook");
        wordlist.add("To ask");
        wordlist.add("Cold");
        wordlist.add("Stem");
        wordlist.add("To dance");
        wordlist.add("Village");
        wordlist.add("Lake");
        wordlist.add("Sick");
        wordlist.add("Pride");
        wordlist.add("To Cook"); // this item 20 in the word array
        wordlist.add("Ink");
        wordlist.add("Angry");
        wordlist.add("Needle");
        wordlist.add("To swim");
        wordlist.add("Voyage");
        wordlist.add("Blue");
        wordlist.add("Lamp");
        wordlist.add("To sin");
        wordlist.add("Bread");
        wordlist.add("Rich");
        wordlist.add("Tree");
        wordlist.add("To prick");
        wordlist.add("Pity");
        wordlist.add("Yellow");
        wordlist.add("Mountain");
        wordlist.add("To die");
        wordlist.add("Salt");
        wordlist.add("New");
        wordlist.add("Custom");
        wordlist.add("To pray"); // this item 40 in the word array
        wordlist.add("Money");
        wordlist.add("Foolish");
        wordlist.add("Pamphlet");
        wordlist.add("Despise");
        wordlist.add("Finger");
        wordlist.add("Expensive");
        wordlist.add("Bird");
        wordlist.add("To fall");
        wordlist.add("Book");
        wordlist.add("Unjust");
        wordlist.add("Frog");
        wordlist.add("To part");
        wordlist.add("Hunger");
        wordlist.add("White");
        wordlist.add("Child");
        wordlist.add("To take care");
        wordlist.add("Lead pencil");
        wordlist.add("Sad");
        wordlist.add("Plum");
        wordlist.add("To marry"); // this item 60 in the word array
        wordlist.add("House");
        wordlist.add("Dear");
        wordlist.add("Glass");
        wordlist.add("To quarrel");
        wordlist.add("Fur");
        wordlist.add("Big");
        wordlist.add("Carrot");
        wordlist.add("To paint");
        wordlist.add("Part");
        wordlist.add("Old");
        wordlist.add("Flower");
        wordlist.add("To beat");
        wordlist.add("Box");
        wordlist.add("Wild");
        wordlist.add("Family");
        wordlist.add("To wash");
        wordlist.add("Cow");
        wordlist.add("Friend");
        wordlist.add("Luck");
        wordlist.add("Lie"); // this item 80 in the word array
        wordlist.add("Deportment");
        wordlist.add("Narrow");
        wordlist.add("Brother");
        wordlist.add("To fear");
        wordlist.add("Stork");
        wordlist.add("False");
        wordlist.add("Anxiety");
        wordlist.add("To kiss");
        wordlist.add("Bride");
        wordlist.add("Pure");
        wordlist.add("Door");
        wordlist.add("To choose");
        wordlist.add("Hay");
        wordlist.add("Contented");
        wordlist.add("Ridicule");
        wordlist.add("To sleep");
        wordlist.add("Month");
        wordlist.add("Nice");
        wordlist.add("Woman");
        wordlist.add("To abuse"); // Phew! this item 100 in the word array
// Word list array is now populated with the basic data


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ArrayList actions outline, code/logic to mange the list. It is outputted to console for test purposes.
// next section outputs formatted list of words
        System.out.println("Contents of the ArrayList of words:");
        for(String str: wordlist)
        {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
// end output formatted list

// this section performs and displays the shuffle operation
        Collections.shuffle(wordlist);
        System.out.println("Results after shuffle operation:");
        for(String str: wordlist)
        {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
// end shuffle section

// prints an unformatted list of words in the ArrayList
        System.out.println(wordlist);

// this queries if the wordlist is populated.  Returns true if empty.  Returns false if populated
        System.out.println("Is ArrayList empty? "+ wordlist.isEmpty());

// finds and prints the index of a given word in the list, in this case 'ship'
        System.out.println("Index of Ship is "+ wordlist.indexOf("Ship"));


// finds the size of the ArrayList and prints to screen
        System.out.println("Size of the ArrayList is: "+ wordlist.size());

// end ArrayList actions design outline

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


// create an introduction message
        String begin ="Welcome! \n\n Press OK to begin the ArrayList GUI demo";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, begin );

// section for main MESSAGE

        JList <String> message = new JList<>(wordlist.toArray(new String[0]));
        //message.setOpaque(true);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(message);
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
//-----------------------------------------------------------------end message

// section for bottom panel
// call wordlist -- find if empty or not, display current size, and find index of sample word --
        sizeBox = new JTextField("  Is ArrayList empty? "+ wordlist.isEmpty() +
            "             Current size of list = "+ wordlist.size() +
            "              Index of the example word 'Ship' is "+ wordlist.indexOf("Ship"),
            JTextField.CENTER);
        sizeBox.setEditable(false);  // ensures that the list text cannot be edited in the panel
        sizeBox.setOpaque(true);
        sizeBox.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));
        sizeBox.setFont( new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 14) );

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------end bottom

// west panel
        ActionListener westListener = new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
            {
                switch ( evt.getActionCommand() )
                {
                    case "Remove all items":
                    System.out.println("Remove all");// demonstrates actionlistener is working
                    break;

                    case "Print List":
                    System.out.println("Print List");
                    break;

                    case "Save to file":
                    System.out.println("Save file");
                    break;

                    case "Quit application":
                    System.out.println("Quit");
                    break;
                }
            }
        };

// create buttons for west panel
        ButtonGroup westGroup = new ButtonGroup();

        removeAll = new JButton("Remove all items");
        westGroup.add(removeAll);
        removeAll.addActionListener(westListener);

        printL = new JButton("Print List");
        westGroup.add(printL);
        printL.addActionListener(westListener);

        saveF = new JButton("Save to file");
        westGroup.add(saveF);
        saveF.addActionListener(westListener);

        quitA = new JButton("Quit application");
        westGroup.add(quitA);
        quitA.addActionListener(westListener);

// ----------------------------------------------------------- end west

// create input box
        inputBox = new JTextField("", JTextField.CENTER);
        inputBox.setEditable(true);  // ensures that the list text cannot be edited in the panel
        inputBox.setOpaque(true);
        inputBox.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));
        inputBox.setFont( new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 22) );
        inputBox.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        inputBox.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
// create add button
        addButton = new JButton("Add to List");

//addButtonListener to take input from word add box and include in ArrayList
        addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
             System.out.println("Add item to list");
             wordlist.add(inputBox.getText() + ", "); // append the input to the list
            }
        });
// ------------------------------------------------- end input box

// start east
        ActionListener eastListener = new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt2)
            {
                switch ( evt2.getActionCommand() )
                {
                    case "A to Z":
                    System.out.println("A to Z");
                    break;

                    case "Z to A":
                    System.out.println("Z to A");
                    break;

                    case "Reverse order":
                    System.out.println("Reverse order");
                    break;

                    case "Random order":
                    System.out.println("Random order");
                    Collections.shuffle(wordlist);
                    break;
                }
            }
        };

// create EAST buttons
        ButtonGroup eastGroup = new ButtonGroup();

        az = new JButton("A to Z");
        eastGroup.add(az);
        az.addActionListener(eastListener);

        za = new JButton("Z to A");
        eastGroup.add(za);
        za.addActionListener(eastListener);

        rev = new JButton("Reverse order");
        eastGroup.add(rev);
        rev.addActionListener(eastListener);

        random = new JButton("Random order");
        eastGroup.add(random);
        random.addActionListener(eastListener);

// end east
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 // arrange the GUI with 4 panels
 // the current ArrayList will be displayed in the center.


        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(15,15,15,15));
        JPanel left = new JPanel();
        JPanel right = new JPanel();
        JPanel center = new JPanel();
        JPanel top = new JPanel();
        JPanel bottom = new JPanel();

// create border layout and populate
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(5,5));
        add(left, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(right, BorderLayout.EAST);
        add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

// place series of grid layouts inside the border layout components
        left.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1));
        right.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1));

        center.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5,5));
        center.add(message,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        center.add(top,BorderLayout.NORTH);

        top.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2,5,5));
        bottom.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2,5,5));

// west panel
        left.add(removeAll);
        left.add(printL);
        left.add(saveF);
        left.add(quitA);

// east panel
         right.add(az);
         right.add(za);
         right.add(rev);
         right.add(random);

// top and bottom panel

        top.add(inputBox);
        top.add(addButton);
        bottom.add(sizeBox);

    } // constructor ends

} // THE END ArrayListGUI
```

Comment: Your code should be minimal, that is, it should not contain irrelevant lines. It makes it harder for us to understand and manipulate.

Comment: What are you trying to manipulate/understand?

Comment: Point taken on the lines used... I'll be cutting down on the white space in future coding

Comment: `I'll be cutting down on the white space` No! You will be cutting on real lines which are not relevant, such as all the button functionality and all the styling.

Comment: Thanks. Any answer to the question posted?

Comment: Looking at it now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert your `ArrayList` to an array which will be used to initialize the `JList`.

```
public class Listing extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Listing();
    }

    Listing() {

        final ArrayList<String> wordlist = new ArrayList<String>();
        wordlist.add("Head");
        wordlist.add("Green");
        wordlist.add("Water");
        wordlist.add("To sing");
        wordlist.add("Dead");
        wordlist.add("Long");
        wordlist.add("Ship");
        wordlist.add("To pay");
        wordlist.add("Window");
        wordlist.add("Friendly");
        wordlist.add("To cook");

        JList<String> displayList = new JList<>(wordlist.toArray(new String[0]));
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(displayList);

        getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking good there so I'll try to build in my program and see how its goes!

Comment: What about handling the input to list? How would I add input to the list?

Comment: @CharlyBear When you clean your code and I can see what your attempt was I'll it to help you.

Comment: Its working. Hurrah! List is displaying... Where do you want me to paste code to?  Scrollbar doesnt seem to work...

Comment: @CharlyBear "Scrollbar doesnt seem to work". It's because you add it and then you override it by adding the list `message` later (see my updated code).

Comment: @CharlyBear As for adding and removing items, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#mutable.

Answer (score 2):

Put your items into [JList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) and put the JList inside a scrollbar.

Comment: Thanks.  This would add nicely to the design unfortunately I failed to implement it as I could not get the program to run after changing the text to a JList!! Also how do I add to the ArrayList from the input and add button at the top of GUI

Comment: I would read up more about why you couldn't get your JList to work as this is almost definitely the best way to go with this.  If you really don't want to you could add the text to a JTextArea which will let you add newlines after each item

Comment: Have done alot of reading (believe it or not!) but cannot find an example that allows me to understand it in such a way to be able to implement it in this program

Comment: Throw us a bone MrWiggles!

Comment: Charly Bear needs a digout!

Comment: What about handling the input to list? How would I add input to the list?

Comment: What do you mean handling input to the list?

Comment: Basically I'm looking to complete aspects of the functionality of the program I've been developing...  I never thought I'd get it this far.

Comment: Handling the input by taking in the user's typing in the text box at the top.  Getting it and adding it to the arraylist.  Also need the arraylist that is displayed to be updated dynamically.

Comment: Similiarly I need to handle functions like actions for the button for sorting A-z and shuffling/random.

Comment: cc Hey MrWiggles...Its working. Hurrah! List is displaying... Where do you want me to paste code to? Scrollbar doesnt seem to work...

Comment: Hey SenorWiggles I updated the code by editing in the main window hope thats right

Comment: You'll want to take a look at what ListModel is and use this as the backing to the JList.  Once you have that figured out adding/deleting/sorting etc. is straight forward

Comment: Nice. What about randomising function?  What would that look like in this program? Its on the bottom right of gui

Comment: I'll check out ListModel

Comment: The ListModel provides an abstraction over your data - all other operations you need are just standard data manipulation, nothing special